# SOAP security negotiation failed after windows security update KB4056892

Tags: wcf, security, soap, windows-update

I have a server which runs this WCF service, this service worked perfectly before the new windows security update KB4056892.

The client which uses the service cannot verify the certificate, if i remove the certificate security it works perfectly. Also if i remove the windows update it will work as usual.

I've tried to change the validation method without any luck.

The certificate is not outdated and tried to test the key with an certificate utility app. The certificate chain and private key was successfully tested.

```
<security>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
</security>
```

*"SOAP security negotiation with 'http://servernameproduction..' for target 'http://servernameproduction..' failed. See inner exception for more details."*

Innerexception: *The X.509 certificate CN=xxx, O=xxx, STREET=xxx, L=xxx, S=xxx, PostalCode=xxx, C=xxx chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.*

UPDATE: https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-0786

Comment: https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-0786